# Ghostscript - Can't find (or can't open) font file

Tags: ghostscript

I try to create a image from a pdf in php (imagemagic). On the image text is missing.

To debug this problem i went to the CLI and use the folowing command:

> `gs -sDevice=png16m -sOutputFile="test.png" test.pdf`

Now I get:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.26 (2018-11-20)
Copyright (C) 2018 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/Resource/Font/ArialMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file ArialMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/Resource/Font/ArialMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file ArialMT.
Querying operating system for font files...
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/Resource/Font/ArialMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file ArialMT.
Loading ArialMT font from /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf... 4395876 2792289 6087360 4693359 4 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/Resource/Font/Arial-BoldMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file Arial-BoldMT.
Loading Arial-BoldMT font from /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/arialbd.ttf... 4395876 2792684 6897144 5444610 4 done.
Can't find CID font "Arial".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-Identity for /Arial, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
The substitute CID font "Adobe-Identity" is not provided either. attempting to use fallback CIDFont.See doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Loading a TT font from /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/Resource/CIDFSubst/DroidSansFallback.ttf to emulate a CID font Adobe-Identity ... Done.
Can't find CMap Identity-UTF16-H building a CIDDecoding resource. 
Warning: falling back to Identity ordering
Loading a TT font from /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/Resource/CIDFSubst/DroidSansFallback.ttf to emulate a CID font CIDFallBack ... Done.
Can't find CMap Identity-UTF16-H building a CIDDecoding resource. 
   **** Error: can't process embedded font stream,
        attempting to load the font using its name.
               Output may be incorrect.
Can't find CID font "Arial".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-Identity for /Arial, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
The substitute CID font "Adobe-Identity" is not provided either. attempting to use fallback CIDFont.See doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Loading a TT font from /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/Resource/CIDFSubst/DroidSansFallback.ttf to emulate a CID font Adobe-Identity ... Done.
Can't find CMap Identity-UTF16-H building a CIDDecoding resource. 
Warning: falling back to Identity ordering
Loading a TT font from /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/Resource/CIDFSubst/DroidSansFallback.ttf to emulate a CID font CIDFallBack ... Done.
Can't find CMap Identity-UTF16-H building a CIDDecoding resource. 
   **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
               Output may be incorrect.
   **** Error: File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.
               Output may be incorrect.
%%BoundingBox: 85 470 562 757
%%HiResBoundingBox: 85.491068 470.681986 561.761983 756.827977
```

---

I found a lot of topics and tried a lot but I can't fix the problem. I think the problem is the CID font but I'm not sure.

Can someone give me some tips how I can solve this problem?

Server: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
Ghostscript: GPL Ghostscript 9.26 (2018-11-20)

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have several problems. It's hard to say for certain because you haven't supplied the PDF file to inspect.

Firstly your PDF file appears to be trying to use a CIDFont called 'Arial' which it does not embed in the PDF file. It also doesn't contain the regular fonts ArialMT and Arial-BoldMT but you appear to have substitute fonts available either from fontmap.GS or via fontconfig (if your build includes that) for those.

Failing to embed fonts is poor practice, failing to embed CIDFonts is specifically frowned upon in the PDF specification.

Ghostscript tries its fallback approaches to define a substitute CIDFont for the missing Arial CIDFont. Firstly it tries the fallback font Adobe-Identity (the name is derived from the CIDSystemInfo) but that CIDFont is also not available. So it drops back to the next attempt, which is to use DroidSansFallback.

However that fails because, in order to produce a satisfactory substitute, Ghostscript needs a CMap, in order to build a CIDDecoding resource. It seems that your installation is missing the relevant CMap.

It looks like your distribution has packaged Ghostscript so that it does not use a ROM file system. Instead it 'looks like' all the files are installed on disk under /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26

You should look for the directory /usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/Resource/CMap and see if there is a file there called Identity-UTF16-H.

I'm going to guess there isn't, and this will be due to a decision made by your package maintainer. I have no idea why they would choose not to include that file but without it (and the other files in that folder) the CIDFont support will be hampered.

If it's not present I'd suggest you take it up with the Debian package maintainer. As Ghostscript is licensed under the AGPL the source code (including all the support files) is of course available from the Ghostscript Git repository and the Ghostscript web site. You could pick up the missing file(s) from there.

Note that the current version is 9.27 and I would recommend upgrading.

Comment: The font was not there as you expected. This is what i have done now:  

sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove ghostscript  
  
wget https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs927/ghostscript-9.27.tar.gz  

tar -zxf ghostscript-9.27.tar.gz  
cd ghostscript-9.27  
./configure  
make  
make install  
  
Now it works. But i also have a new problem. ImageMagic can't find gs. So i probably have to edit some config file or update a path.

Comment: Sounds like Ghostscript was re-installed in a different path (probably including the 9.27 number and IM is probably looking in 9.26). I don't know a lot about IM, but you could look in the delegates.xml file and see if you find it in there. Or you could set up a sybolic link form 9.27 to 9.26 perhaps. I would suggest that you flag this to the package maintainer on Debian because you won't be the only person with this problem.